# Cannot play videos in my iPad Air after upgrading to iOS 8.0.2

Tags: ios, ipad

After upgrading my iPad Air to iOS 8.0.2 I can no longer play videos in any application.

I've tried playing videos in Safari, Youtube, MVP Video Playlist, and any other app you can think of and nothing, I even tried playing purchased videos from iTunes in Apple's own Videos app and it just doesn't work.

Is anybody else experimenting this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting this same question in Apple Support Communities Diavonex quickly replied with a simple solution:

> (A) Try reset iPad
>
> Hold the Sleep/Wake and Home button down together until you see the Apple Logo.
>
> Note: Data will not be affected.
>
> (B) Close all apps in the multi-task window
>
> 1.Double-click the Home button.
>
> 2. Swipe the app's preview up to close it.
> 3. Preview will fly off the screen.

Reference: https://discussions.apple.com/message/26841501#26841501